# Filtering multiple categories with URL queries

Tags: categories, relations, filter, relatedto, querystring

I am trying to filter using categories. I have to filters type and size, in the url.

```
/products.html?size=medium,large&type=polo-shirt,jeans
```

In my template, I am doing the following

```
{% set sizes = craft.app.request.getQueryParam('size') %}
{% set types = craft.app.request.getQueryParam('type') %}

{% set relationParam = ['and'] %}

{# type #}
{% if types %}
  {% for i in types|split(",") %}
    {% set type = craft.categories.group('types').slug(i) %}
    {% set relationParam = relationParam|merge([{ targetElement: type }]) %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}

{# sizes #}
{% if sizes %}
  {% for i in sizes|split(",") %}
    {% set size = craft.categories.group('sizes').slug(i) %}
    {% set relationParam = relationParam|merge([{ targetElement: size }]) %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}

{# Avoid passing an array with `['and']` only #}
{% if relationParam|length < 2 %}
  {% set relationParam = '' %}
{% endif %}

{% set entries = craft.entries({
    section: 'products',
    relatedTo:  relationParam
}) %}

<div class="listings-container">
  {% if entries|length %}
    {% for entry in entries %}
        {% include "partials/_listing.html" %}
    {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
</div>
```

The problem I'm having is as follows:

1. I click on “medium” in sizes, it shows all products that have the category “medium”
2. I then, click on “large” in sizes, it shows one result because it’s searching for products that have all 2 categories (“medium”, “large”)
3. I then click on "polo-shirt" in types, this now shows all products that have all 3 categories (“medium”, “large", "polo-shirt")
4. I then click on “jeans” in sizes, this now shows no results as its trying to find products that have all 4 categories (“medium”, “large", "polo-shirt", "jeans")

What I am trying to achieve is find all the products that are “medium” or “large" sizes and of "polo-shirt" or “jeans” types

Comment: Would it be an option to do it in PHP? Because it's a mess in Twig

Comment: @RobinSchambach nope, it needs to be Twig I'm afraid

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue with your current code is that you're looping over each type/size category, creating a parameter in your `relatedTo` query for *each one*. This means that you're currently creating a query that looks like this:

```
relatedTo([
    'and',
    { targetElement: 1 },
    { targetElement: 2 },
    { targetElement: 3 },
    { targetElement: 4 }
])
```

...which, combined with the `AND`, means that Craft will only return entries that have all of these relations.

What you need to do, is to *collect the IDs for each category group in an array, and add those arrays to the `relatedTo` query* – i.e. create a query that looks like this:

```
relatedTo([
    'and',
    { targetElement: [1, 2] },
    { targetElement: [3, 4] }
])
```

The above query would solve your issue, because whenever Craft isn't given an `and` or `or`, it assumes `or`. This means that the above query is exactly the same as the below:

```
relatedTo([
    'and',
    { targetElement: ['or', 1, 2] },
    { targetElement: ['or', 3, 4] }
])
```

Essentially, the above query is saying: give me all entries that have a relation matching either the target element 1 OR 2, AND a relation matching either the target element 3 or 4.

Here's how the Twig to create a query like the above could look:

```
{# Create the base query #}
{% set query = craft.entries({ section: 'products' }) %}

{% set relatedTo = [] %}

{% set types = craft.app.request.getQueryParam('type')|split(',')|filter %}
{% if types %}
    {% set relatedTo = relatedTo|merge([{
        targetElement: craft.categories({ group: 'types', slug: types }).ids()
    }]) %}
{% endif %}

{% set sizes = craft.app.request.getQueryParam('size')|split(',')|filter %}
{% if sizes %}
    {% set relatedTo = relatedTo|merge([{
        targetElement: craft.categories({ group: 'sizes', slug: sizes }).ids()
    }]) %}
{% endif %}

{% if relatedTo|length > 1 %}
    {% set relatedTo = ['and']|merge(relatedTo) %}
{% endif %}

{% set entries = query.relatedTo(relatedTo ? relatedTo : null).all() %}
```

The above code should work for all the below use cases:

- /products (returns all product entries)
- /products?type=polo-shirt (returns all polo shirts)
- /products?type=polo-shirt&size=small (returns all small polo shirts)
- /products?type=polo-shirt,jeans&size=small (returns all small polo shirts and jeans)
- /products?type=polo-shirt,jeans&size=small,medium (returns all small and medium polo shirts and jeans)

Note that the usage of `ids()` over `all()` in a few places (such as in the `craft.categories` queries to get the type and size categories) – this is a performance tweak (it's more effective to just pull the IDs than the entire model).

Also note that if you want to use pagination, just amend the final line to

```
{% paginate query.relatedTo(relatedTo ? relatedTo : null).limit(10) as pageInfo, pageEntries %}
```

***Note:** I originally typed out a completely different answer to this question, but after some helpful discussion with @Robin Schambach on Slack, we arrived on the above, IMO much better solution. Cheers Robin!*